# wicket: back button previous page

Tags: java, javascript, html, wicket

Firstly, I have to say that I am new in Wicket. I would like to implement a back-button sothat when someone clicks on it, he belongs to the previous page.

Can someone give me the first hint plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to do it using JavaScript.

```
window.history.back();
```

Check it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp